# Visual Studio 2013 Hangs on WinCE Deployment for C++ App not C#

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2013, deployment, windows-ce

Have a weird behavior in Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition Update 5 when I try to deploy an application on my Windows Embedded Compact 2013 device. In my solution I have a C++ and a C# project, both for my WinCE device. When I press BUILD -> "Deploy myApp" it works for the C# application perfectly but for the C++ project VS 2013 just hangs. In the left bottom corner I see "Deploy started..." and that's it. Even after 15 minutes nothing changed, no error message. I have to close VS with the Task Manager.

On another computer I can deploy both projects. Same configuration, add-ins and plugins.

Deployment is over TCP/IP.

What I tried so far:

- Repair VS 2013
- Reinstall VS 2013 with Update 4
- Reinstall WinCE SDK

Anybody any idea where I should look or what I should test?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens also on some of my machines.
The only solution I found is to set the target IP address into the project properties (in the debugging tab) before download.
In this way Visual Studio will not ask for the IP and everything* works.

*everything debugging related, at least :)

Comment: Worked! Thank you! Btw. it's a Toradex board ;-)